# How to delete old obsolete terms after node's term field has been updated?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Because the old version of the term is left in the vocabulary and not deleted or updated with the new term.

So what I mean is that vocabulary should contain only terms that exist on at least one node.

I need this because I'm using certain vocabulary on Views as exposed filter and old terms leftovers messes it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better description of what you're looking for is "orphaned terms". There exists a module that addresses that use case, called [Delete Orphaned Terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/delete_orphaned_terms).

> This is a utility module for deleting "orphaned" taxonomy terms. By
>   default, terms with zero nodes associated with them are considered
>   orphans, though administrators can specify the number of nodes
>   associated with a term in order for it to be considered an orphan.